# Using ng-style inside a dynamic ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I have a dynamic `ng-repeat` where the user can change the number of items.

**Simplified JS:**

```
$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$scope.getBoxBackgroundColor = function () { return '#FF0000'; }
$scope.addItem = function () { $scope.items.push($scope.items.length + 1); }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-style="{ 'backgroundColor': getBoxBackgroundColor() }"></div>
<button ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
```

**Problem:**

The `ng-style` directive is not calling `getBoxBackgroundColor` function when a new item is added.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not `backgroundColor`, it's `background-color` or just `background`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/doxfuuk8/1/

Comment: I cannot understand the problem, just call `$scope.getBoxBackgroundColor()` inside the `$scope.addItem()` function

Comment: @Daniel_L backgroundColor works too.

Comment: @Michelem I don't get your point. If you run my code, all items will be with a red background, but when you add a new item, the background-color property will not be added.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, thank you! It was a mistake at my original code. Problem solved.